# Error: Could not start a new session in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, bdd

I seem to be getting the following error in my Eclipse when running my testcase via my Step Definition in my Automation Framework:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: '192.168.1.104', ip: '2a01:4b00:9f00:8d00:f548:778e:6ba3:875d%en0'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:549)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at stepDefinitions.GreenKartStepDefinition.user_is_on_green_Cart_landing_page(GreenKartStepDefinition.java:24)
    at ✽.User is on GreenCart Landing page(file:///Users/imtiyaz/Downloads/WebDriverAutomationProject%202/CucumberFramework/src/test/java/features/searchProduct.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
```

I did download 'Chrome for Testing' from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads as I am using Chrome version 115.0.5790.102.

I set it in my code as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/imtiyaz/Documents/Google Chrome for Testing" );
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, here I have kept my chrome driver inside my working directory.

```java
public static WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(new String[] { "--ignore-certificate-errors" });
driver = (WebDriver)new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Driver server process died prematurely" indicates that there was an issue with the ChromeDriver server process. This typically happens when the ChromeDriver executable is not able to start or communicate with the Chrome browser properly

1. the driver version and the browser version should be matched
2. ChromeDriver executable permissions
3. Invalid ChromeDriver path

The path should point to the location of the ChromeDriver executable, not the Chrome browser itself

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/imtiyaz/Documents/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium `v4.11.0` has been released yesterday(31-Jul23). This version can do the driver management automatically even for chrome browser `v115`, without setting the PATH(`System.setProperty`).

**Solution:** Just upgrade to Selenium `v4.11.0` and use the simple code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");

}
```

If you want to use `ChromeForTesting` browser for specific reason, then download the `v115` driver(`chromedriver.exe`) and browser(`chrome.exe`) from the following link - https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

After downloading, use the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Backup\\Selenium jars\\drivers\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe"); //115 chromedriver.exe
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Backup\\Selenium jars\\browsers\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe"); //115 chrome.exe
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");        
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

**New "Chrome For testing" browser logo is slightly different(See below)**: Left side is regular Chrome browser and right side is new Chrome For Testing browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I updated my Selenium version to 4.11.0 in my pom.xml file and also used your simplified code to invoke ChromeDriver. 

This time I am getting following error:

WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 115, so returning the closest version found: 114
FAILED: runScenario("Search Experience for product search in both home and Offers page", "Search and Place the order for Products")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Selenium version to 4.11.0 in my pom.xml file and also used your simplified code to invoke ChromeDriver.

This time I am getting following error:

```
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 115, so returning the closest version found: 114
FAILED: runScenario("Search Experience for product search in both home and Offers page", "Search and Place the order for Products")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
```

This is my code

```
package stepDefinitions;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class GreenKartStepDefinition {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String landingPageProductName;
    public String offerPageProductName;
    
    @Given("User is on GreenCart Landing page")
    public void user_is_on_green_Cart_landing_page() {
        
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");
        
    
        
    }
    @When("user searched with Shortname {string} and extracted actual name of product")
    public void user_searched_with_shortname_and_extracted_actual_name_of_product(String shortName) {
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='search']")).sendKeys(shortName);
    String landingPageproductName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4.product-name")).getText().split("-")[0].trim();
    System.out.println(landingPageproductName +"is extracted from Home page");
    
    }
    
    @Then("user searched for {string} shortname in offers page to check if product exists with same name ")
    public void user_searched_for_same_shortname_in_offers_page_to_check_if_product_exists(String shortName) throws InterruptedException {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Top Deals")).click();
     Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles(); //So when we call this method 'getWndowHandles', Parent window is there & chidd  window is there - will fall in this s1 object
     Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator(); //The 2 windwows We are storing in 1 set collection type - in 0th index you have parent window, in 1st omdex you have child window
     //To retrieve those items from the 'Set' collection, I'll use the iterator method
     //'i1' is responsibile for retrieving
     String parentWindow = i1.next(); //This will call the 0th index (parent window id)
     String childWindow = i1.next(); //When we call i1.next again, will go 1 level up and call the child window (1st index)
     driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='search'")).sendKeys(shortName);
     
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     offerPageProductName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr td:nth-child(1)")).getText();


     
    }
    
    @Then("Validate product name in offers page matches with Landing Page")
     public void validate_product_name_in_Offers_page()
     {
        Assert.assertEquals(offerPageProductName, landingPageProductName);
     }
        

}
```

Comment: No, you should create a brand new question, not ask another question in the old question.